# My phone is stuck In Twrp Mode And Touch is not working in this mode. And i am not normally booting. Please Guide?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, twrp, touch

I wanted to root my Samsung Galaxy S4 And flash a rom but when i installed a TWRP recovery its touch is not working at all.Only power button works which turn off the screen.How can i exit from it? or How can i flash another Twrp whose touch is working.?

Comment: Open back cover and pull out your battery?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a few years back, 
After looking everywhere and not finding a solution I felt like an imbecile when I realised what to do, so be prepared ... >_<

I used an OTG Cable and a USB mouse and everything worked fine :)

I was porting TWRP to my device and accidentally set the screen rotation the wrong way, It is still the wrong way with a mouse but a lot easier to navigate.

Comment: What cable did you use? I'm in the same situation stuck in TWRP, broken screen, but nothing will register. I've tried Logitech USB keyboard, mouse/ wired mouse keyboard, nothing.